# Do I need to have Python installed on my machine to run a code in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I want to create a python virtual environment in a Windows network folder, and then activate and use this venv on another computer. My question is, do I need to have python installed on all these machines that i want to use this virtual environment?

If so, why do I need to install python everywhere if it's already inside this venv i will create, along with all the necessary packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual environments are not designed to be portable. For instance, if you have entry points installed then moving them to another machine would break their shebang lines. And even if you do it on your local machine there's no guarantee something else wasn't structured to be directory-specific such as your username! Take in consideration that when creating Python venv, it will be pointed to your python path where your username is part of the path, so its not a good idea. Although why not upload py files to the cloud, share via Bluetooth to phone or copy-paste to a usb stick.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that's why when I was trying to activate the virtual environment on another computer, it would still try to search for python in the directory which this venv was originally created.